# Convert complex music score to simpler one

Tags: theory, software

I am currently trying to implement a software that can convert a complex music score ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O79xP27Rk38)) to a simpler one ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov3qZkGTjdI)).

Do you guys know any technique or work that have been done before in order to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like in the simple one it converted the rolled out chords to just the root notes, and eliminated the decorations on the right hand. What kind of input do you hope for the software to accept? MIDI? Because that looks like it could, depending on how simplified you want it, be pretty "simple" (software terms).

Comment: Yes, I prefer MIDI.

Comment: Actually, I just want to know the method to convert them to root nodes only. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example there are two main differences between the advanced and the easy. The first is the number of notes played at one time. Each hand seems to only play one note at a time in the easy version. This could be accomplished automatically by limiting the note output notes to the highest and the lowest in some way. The other difference is the rhythm seems less complex in the easy version. This can be accomplished through quantization which many music programs can do. In addition there may be range considerations. I didn't listen to the whole examples so I'm not sure if they did that or not. But many easy versions is pieces will limit the range that is used. This can be accomplished by transposing your output to within a certain range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific on how to limit the notes played at one time? As it seems that selecting the highest note is not always procedure the same rhythm.

Comment: To be more details, I want to process a large number of midi files. The output should be as simple as possible (I expected it just single sequence of notes, 1 note at a time) so they can be analyzed easier.